# Display welcome screen for my phonegap app (no java)

Tags: android, cordova

I followed this link

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#_splash_screens

created splash.png 
config.xml

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
<gap:splash src="ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
```

original files were of this dimension 240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi

Then I chked on this url
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html to generate 
9 patch

nothing seems to work

pl help

Comment: did you install the splash screen plugin?

Comment: yes<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, but you should use the latest version from npm ```<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"/>```

Comment: I added source tag. but not working. As a workaround,  I am creating a simple show with 4 images

Comment: <script language="JavaScript">
var i = 0;
var path = new Array();
 
// LIST OF IMAGES
path[0] = "image_1.gif";
path[1] = "image_2.gif";
path[2] = "image_3.gif";

function swapImage()
{
   document.slide.src = path[i];
   if(i < path.length - 1) i++; else i = 0;
   setTimeout("swapImage()",3000);
}
window.onload=swapImage;
</script>
<img height="200" name="slide" src="image_1.gif" width="400" />

Comment: As splash doesn't seem to work. I wanted to create a slideshow on - body onload function. <script language="JavaScript">
var i = 0
var path = new Array();
path[0] = "img1.gif";
path[1] = "img2.gif";

function swapImage()
{
   document.slide.src = path[i];
   if(i < path.length - 1) i++; else i = 0;
   setTimeout("swapImage()",1000);
}
window.onload=swapImage;
</script>
<img  name="slide" src="img1.gif"  />  Only img1.gif is displayed on load, rest of the images are not displayed. I thought of putting in simple demo screenshots in splash screen, now slideshow burns

Comment: any answers. Or otherwise, in place of a slideshow, even a demo video would do good. I tried  <gap:plugin name="com.moust.cordova.videoplayer" version="1.0.0" /> <gap:plugin name="com.dawsonloudon.videoplayer" version="1.0.0"  /> In my index.html VideoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/movie.mp4");. but nothing seems to work. I need to publish my app with instructions. pl help